# I can't find my htc android device attached to my PC.

Tags: android

I'm trying below line of code in the command prompt after attaching my android device to PC.
***"D:\Android 2.3\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools>adb devices"*** and I can't find any device, due to this I'm unable to deploy my android application to my device.
 Please help me and guide me if i forgot any step.
thanks
Mayur

Comment: install htc drivers too.. i mean pc suit..

Comment: @sandy I did that as well but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you set your phone to usb debugging mode???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly has this every worked?

Secondly you will need to install the HTC drivers for your OS and device.

Thirdly did you set your phone to `USB debugging` mode?

Comment: Thanks mate. It was because of my devise I Changed the settings according to your questions and it worked for me.